# How to fail gitlab CI build?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I am trying to fail a build in gitlab CI and get email notification about it.

My build script is this:

```
echo "Listing files!"
ls -la

echo "##########################Preparing build##########################"
mkdir build
cd build
echo "Generating make files"
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=on ..

echo "##########################Building##########################"
make
```

I have commited the code that breaks build. However, instead of finishing, build seems to be stuck in "running" state after exiting make. Last line is:

```
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I also get no notifications.

How can i diagnose what is happening?

Upd.: in runner, following is repeated in log:

```
Submitting build <..> to coordinator...response error: 500
```

In `production.log` and `sideq.log` of gitlab_ci, following is written:

```
ERROR: Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (ECONNREFUSED)
```

Full message with stacktrace is here: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/6XfViB4u).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, i can help you with a workaround but im trying to fully fix it.

1- most of the times he hangs but the jobs keeps on going and actually finishes it, you can see the processes inside the machine, example: in my case it compiles and in the end it uses docker to publish the build, so the process docker doesn't exist until he reaches that phase.

2- to workaround this issue you have to make the data persistent and "retry" the download over and over again until he downloads everything he needs.

PS: stating what kind of OS you are using always helps.